# `each` loop with additional parameter

Tags: ruby, loops, iteration, each

I expected `row` to be `[0, 0, 0, 0]` and `row_index` to be `nil` in the following:

```
img_array = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
]

img_array.each do |row, row_index|
  ...
end
```

Actually, `row` is `0` and `row_index` is `0`. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. It is not even valid.

Comment: @sawa It runs fine for me in ruby-2.2.2, and produces the described result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
img_array = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6, 7],
  [8, 9, 0, 1]
]
```

We have:

```
enum = img_array.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 0, 1]]:each>
```

[Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) therefore creates an enumerator that is an instance of the class [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html). The method [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) passes each element of `enum` to the block and assigns the block variables:

```
enum.each { |row, row_index| puts "row=#{row}, row_index=#{row_index}" }
  # row=0, row_index=1
  # row=4, row_index=5
  # row=8, row_index=9
```

We can see what each of the elements of `enum` are by using the method [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next):

```
enum.next #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

Whoops! I forgot to reset the enumerator:

```
enum.rewind
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 0, 1]]:each>

enum.next #=> [0, 1, 2, 3] 
enum.next #=> [4, 5, 6, 7] 
enum.next #=> [8, 9, 0, 1] 
enum.next #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

Alternatively, we could convert the enumerator to an array (no need to `rewind`):

```
enum.to_a #=> [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 0, 1]]
```

When the element (`[0, 1, 2, 3]`) is passed to the block, the block variables are assigned as follows:

```
row, row_index = [0, 1, 2, 3]            #=> [0, 1, 2, 3] 
row                                      #=> 0
row_index                                #=> 1
```

If the variables were `|row, row_index, col_index|`, the assignment would be:

```
row, row_index, col_index = [0, 1, 2, 3] #=> [0, 1, 2, 3] 
row                                      #=> 0
row_index                                #=> 1
col_index                                #=> 2
```

If they were `|row, row_index, *rest|`, it would be:

```
row, row_index, *rest = [0, 1, 2, 3]     #=> [0, 1, 2, 3] 
row                                      #=> 0
row_index                                #=> 1
rest                                     #=> [2, 3]
```

This is called [parallel (or multiple) assignment](https://books.google.ca/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=ruby+parallel+assignment&source=bl&ots=fJEnA9byfE&sig=X9RuIeJR5-Wg4X4Y_N8P-iYRfTk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEAQ6AEwCDgKahUKEwjYgeGV3JvJAhXHJiYKHbm8BwE#v=onepage&q=ruby%20parallel%20assignment&f=false). You can read up on the rules for such assignments at the link I've given.

Comment: Excellent answer. Form this I understood what was OP's question actually :D

Comment: Cary this makes total sense! Thank you for your clear, in-depth input. I have a better understanding of how enumerators work now.

Answer (score 1):

The method `.each()` on array in Ruby will call your block with only one argument.
So if you write your code like this:

```
img_array.each do |row, row_index|
  # do something here
end
```

It will equivalent to this:

```
img_array.each do |element|
  row, row_index = element
  # and now
  # row = element[0]
  # row_index = element[1]
end
```

---

I made an example that easier to understand

```
img_array = [
  ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'],
  ['f', 'g', 'h', 'j']
]

img_array.each do |row, row_index|
    p row
    p row_index
end
```

And the result will be:

```
"a"
"b"
"f"
"g"
```

Run it online here: https://ideone.com/ifDaVZ

Comment: I checked it out, and it runs just as you said. Thank you for you explanation. It really helped me out!

Comment: @EricOrel You're welcome. If this answer solve your problem, please mark this answer as accepted so others can find it easier.